# Broken Recovery Method

Tags: java, android, file, filereader

I have an application that can create backups of its information and recover them. I was working on a seventh version, and found that the recovery method would not work. It acted as if it did, but would do nothing. I could not figure out what was causing this, so I decided to simply start over from my sixth version.

None of my versions' recovery methods work now, despite passing all tests in the past.

It does not throw an error or anything else. It tells the user "The backup has been restored." with a toast. If ext storage isn't allowed, it throws an error. If the file path doesn't exist, throws an error. Nothing abnormal on logcat. But when everything's right, it just simply doesn't work. So...here's the recovery method from a stable version. Let me know if there's anything else you'd like to examine.

Edit: Changed method of decoding from Base64 and setting it to a string. End result still same. Narrowed down issue to the while loop, which never runs, so no information is actually processed.

```
//Method025: Imports user acc settings from a file on a specified path.
public void importFile() {
    //The file variable to be imported.
    File file;

    try {
        //Used to access settings.
        TinyDB database = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());

        //Sets the file equal to the file found at the specified path.
        String strfilePath = database.getString("FilePath");
        file = new File(strfilePath);

        //To be used to arrange the imported information.
        ArrayList<String> strAcc = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> strUser = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> strPass = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> strAdditionalInfo = new ArrayList<>();

        //To be used to store all the information for additional info variables. This is
        //due to its multi-line nature requiring a slightly different method of
        //importation, the other variables are expected to be one line.
        String strExtraInfo = "";

        //Goes through the file and adds info to arrays for each corresponding variable.
        //If the line does not have an identifier, it assumes it to be an additional
        //info line, and will be processed later.
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;

            String strLine = br.readLine();
            //Decodes the line from Base64 and converts it to a string.
            byte[] decodedContent = Base64.decode(strLine.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            strLine = new String (decodedContent);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (strLine.contains("[Acc]")) {
                    strLine = strLine.replace("[Acc]","");
                    strAcc.add(strLine);
                } else if (strLine.contains("[User]")) {
                    strLine = strLine.replace("[User]", "");
                    strUser.add(strLine);
                } else if (strLine.contains("[Pass]")) {
                    strLine = strLine.replace("[Pass]", "");
                    strPass.add(strLine);
                } else  {
                    strExtraInfo += strLine;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Putting the whole code doesn't help.  Please execute this code either with Debug activated or at least print traces.

Comment: Could it be that the backup file itself is broken in such a way that previous versions are unable to load it?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique, sorry, do you want logcat? It's extremely late and haven't slept, not sure exactly what you'd like. xs0 No, I've tried multiple backups/creating new backups. I've checked the files themselves in notepad to make sure they're the correct format etc.

Comment: hmm, in the while loop you seem to read `line`, but then use `strLine` in the if statements..?

Comment: strLine  is equal to br.readLine(), it's probably unnecessary to have a variable but it works. I'm currently doing all the error checking I can think of, and I just confirmed that it IS getting the text from the file using br.readLine()/strLine, so whatever issue happens sometime after reading the file. Will update as I narrow it down.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the value of `savedInfo`. If you have, then what is `database`, because that must be where the problem stems from? Is it a class from a library?

Comment: Database is TinyDB, a method of using shared preferences. I've already made sure it works. I have not printed out savedInfo yet. I did just run across what may be causing it; when printing out strLine as soon as it is declared, it prints out the right value. After it's decoded from Base64, it prints out the wrong value. I used an online decoder to double check, and the file is correctly encoded. That would suggest there's some issue with the method to decode it, and the improper decoding would cause no values to be restored. Double checking etc atm. Thanks, by the way, really appreciate it.

Comment: @LeoAso  Seems as if the issue lies within byte[] decodedContent = Base64.decode(strLine.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);   No idea why.

Comment: I don't think your strLine = decodedContent.toString(); will work. That's a byte[].toString(). Try strLine = new String(decodedContent);

Comment: @GabrielCosta  Legit I'm editing my question right now to reflect that, was hoping it would fix it. It still does nothing, however

Comment: I just tested it here in a small project.

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  byte[] strBytes = { 65, 66, 67, 68 };
  System.out.println(strBytes.toString());
  System.out.println(new String(strBytes));
 }
}

It prints: [B@15db9742 for the byte[].toString() and ABCD using the String constructor

Comment: @GabrielCosta Sorry, I wasn't clear. Using strLine = new String(decodedContent); does work, but it does not fix the overall issue with the project.

Comment: Notice that you're only decoding strLine variable and you're using the line variable inside the while loop, without decoding it. Is it intended? It doesn't look like it is.

Comment: @GabrielCosta I need to go run some registration forms into student services, I'll take a look at it when I get back. I can't remember my intention when I first programmed it.

Comment: It seems to me you should be using strLine instead of line inside your while condition. If you file is entirely encoded, you should also move the decode method to the loop. As it is right now, you only decode the first line and test n times the same line (n being the number of lines). It really doesn't make sense to do that

Comment: @GabrielCosta just got back. So  - the code as is decodes the entire file. Looking over it, it seems like you're right and that it should only decode one line. It doesn't though...so don't really know what to say. I did try to implement the changes, but resulted in a crash. I was in a rush and didn't look at log, but I do believe the while loop has errors, and I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was completely different from first believed, and there ended up being ***many*** problems. The main ones are as listed.

I assume passing the tests in the past was on account of human error, and the question has been changed to reflect that.

- Incorrect method of decoding Base64
- Converting to Base64 and back messed up line spacing
- ReadLine() can only be called once, doing so more returns nothing
- Not enough error checking for things such as strAdditionalInfo.size > 0
- Substring recovery method throws many errors, as can be done more simply using split()

Here is the updated code, fully functional.

```
public void importFile() {
        //The file variable to be imported.
        File file;

        try {
            //Used to access settings.
            TinyDB database = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());

            //Sets the file equal to the file found at the specified path.
            String strfilePath = database.getString("FilePath");
            file = new File(strfilePath);

            //To be used to arrange the imported information.
            ArrayList<String> strAcc = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> strUser = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> strPass = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> strAdditionalInfo = new ArrayList<>();

            //To be used to store all the information for additional info variables. This is
            //due to its multi-line nature requiring a slightly different method of
            //importation, the other variables are expected to be one line.
            String strExtraInfo = "";

            //Goes through the file and adds info to arrays for each corresponding variable.
            //If the line does not have an identifier, it assumes it to be an additional
            //info line, and will be processed later.
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

                String line;
                String strLine;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.contains("[Acc]")) {
                        strLine = line.replace("[Acc]","");
                        strAcc.add(strLine);
                    } else if (line.contains("[User]")) {
                        strLine = line.replace("[User]", "");
                        strUser.add(strLine);
                    } else if (line.contains("[Pass]")) {
                        strLine = line.replace("[Pass]", "");
                        strPass.add(strLine);
                    } else  {
                        strExtraInfo += line;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Gets the list of accounts.
            ArrayList<String> savedInfo = new ArrayList<>(database.getListString("allSaved"));

            //To be used to get the AdditionalInfo variables one line at a time.
            String strSubInfo;

            //Gets rid of any erroneous spaces.
            while (strExtraInfo.contains("  ")) {
                strExtraInfo = strExtraInfo.replace("  ", " ");
            }

            Log.d("STRExtraInfo",strExtraInfo);
            strExtraInfo = strExtraInfo.replace("[ExtraStart]","");
            String array[] = strExtraInfo.split("\\[ExtraEnd\\]");
            ArrayList<String> strRawAdditionalInfo = new ArrayList<>();
            strRawAdditionalInfo = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));

            for (String info : strRawAdditionalInfo){
                strAdditionalInfo.add(info);
                Log.d("ExtraInfo",info );
            }

            //Arranges the information.
            for (String name : strAcc) {
                savedInfo.add(name);

                ArrayList<String> allInfo = new ArrayList<>();

                //Gets the info then adds it to database.
                //Deletes the old information.
                if (strUser.size() > 0) {
                    allInfo.add(strUser.get(0));
                    strUser.remove(0);
                }

                if (strPass.size() > 0) {
                    allInfo.add(strPass.get(0));
                    strPass.remove(0);
                }

                if (strAdditionalInfo.size() > 0) {
                    allInfo.add(strAdditionalInfo.get(0));
                    strAdditionalInfo.remove(0);
                }
                database.putListString(name,allInfo);
            }
```